# External USB storage not visible in the android file system (from android 13)

Tags: android, usb, storage, android-external-storage

My Android application reads and writes to an external storage device with an external library. Since Android 13, we cannot see the USB device as a mount device in the file tree (under /storage) in Android Studio. The files app shows the USB drive correctly and with the storage access framework and ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE access is possible.

As my app depends on an external library, a Java file is required for file access.

Are there any special permissions or security configurations required for the external USB drive or is access only possible with the Storage Access Framework?

[image]